# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined after using Polymer vulcanize

Tags: javascript, polymer, ecmascript-6, polymer-starter-kit, vulcanize

My application based on [Polymer-PSK+](https://github.com/StartPolymer/polymer-starter-kit-plus) and `ES2015`. Using my distributed version of the application I'll receive the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined (elements.js line 5832)`

The reason for this is due to 'missing' properties of Polymer paper-input-container-underline element, see:

[image]

[image]

The assignment to `properties[m[1]]` fails due to `(m[2] || m[3]).trim();`:

`m[2] = "" 
and m[3] = undefined`

Any hints how to solve this problem and how to use the distributed version of my application?

Answer (score 0):

On javascript, both empty strings ("") and the undefined value considered falsy values.

so when you write ("" || undefined), the returned value will be the last falsy value, on this case, undefined, and you cannot perform method calls on an undefined value.

[you can read about it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: The elements.js script is a compiled/generated script coming from `vulcanize`. So there is no way to change the generated output for me (AFAIK)

Comment: In that case, you should edit the title of your post, it is misleading.